# findPreference in a Honeycomb-compliant preference screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

My scenario is simple: one of my preferences is a premium feature that is activated only when the user has purchased an in-app product.

I have a `PreferenceScreen` that is both compliant to pre-Honeycomb and post-Honeycomb Fragment model.

Example fragment

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class SocialPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_social);
                    findPreference(getString(R.string.preference_donateBitcoin))
            .setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
```

Example fragment 2

```
    private void setupSimplePreferencesScreen() {
    if (!isSimplePreferences(this)) {
        return;
    }

    // In the simplified UI, fragments are not used at all and we instead
    // use the older PreferenceActivity APIs.

    // Add 'general' preferences.

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_social);
            findPreference(getString(R.string.preference_donateBitcoin))
            .setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
```

These two fragments, one in a `PreferenceFragment` class and another in the `PreferenceActivity`, manage creation of preferences.

Now the problem is: I'm in a callback method and I need to access a preference to enable it if the SKU is purchased

```
    @Override
public void onPurchasedAsyncListenerResult(String sku, boolean isPurchased) {
    if (PremiumManager.SKU_AUTO_CONNECT.equals(sku)) {
        Preference pref;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            ///WHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAT?;
        else
        pref = findPreference(getString(R.string.preference_autoconnect));
        pref.setEnabled(isPurchased);
    }

}
```

Calling `findPreference` on an ICS tablet returns null, so a NPE is thrown. How do I retrieve the preference object when I use fragments in Preference Screen?